Объеденить 3 валидации в одну (Python)
Есть 3 поля, которые проходят валидацию (при регистрации нового пользователя):
username, password и год рождения. username проверяется на уникальность, пароль на сложность, а год просто на формат 1900 < age < текущий год.
Для каждого поля есть функция конкретно под  проверку этого поля, но эти функции по сути практически одинаковы. В реальном проекте такое было бы уместно?
Есть ли смысл писать одну большую функцию, которая сначала понимает что это за поле, а потом его проверяет?
Ещё смотрю в сторону ООП, но я сейчас вообще не понимаю его принципов.
Как сделать правильно? Как делают в коммерческой разработке?
